# Regex matches from right instead of left

Tags: regex, typescript, ecmascript-6

I don't know if I diagnosed the issue correctly, but it seems the analyzer starts from right to left, instead of from left to right.

My regex is: `\/root\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)\/(.+)$`, and my trial sentence is `irrelevant/root/user/course/exercise/custom/folder/file.txt`

The match is correct, but not the groups. I want to get:

- group 1: user
- group 2: course
- group 3: exercise
- group 4: custom/folder/file.txt *(basically everything that goes after the previous groups)*.

I'm running this on TS and playing with it on regex101.com (ES set)

Comment: Use negated character classes, `\/root\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.+)$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zcykI3/1))

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
\/root\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/(.*)$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/4nVaqe/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  root                     'root'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```